# Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object in \modules\fbconnect\fbconnect.pages.inc on line 230

Tags: facebook, drupal-7, drupal-modules

in drupal 7 , i'm using the 'Facebook connect' module to give the users the possibility to login in my website with their facebook account , the configuration of the module is good ,but when i click on the ((Log in to NameSite with Facebook account)) i face this error msg :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object
>   in
>   C:......\sites\all\modules\fbconnect\fbconnect.pages.inc
>   on line 230

Answer (score 0):

On your server make the folder 'libraries' at /sites/all/libraries and place the facebook-php-sdk folder there. The newest facebook sdk folder is called facebook-php-sdk-master, rename it to facebook-php-sdk if you are using it.